# Passing on named variable arguments in python

Tags: python, variadic-functions

Say I have the following methods:

```
def methodA(arg, **kwargs):
    pass

def methodB(arg, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

In methodA I wish to call methodB, passing on the kwargs. However, it seems that if I define `methodA` as follows, the second argument will be passed on as positional rather than named variable arguments.

```
def methodA(arg, **kwargs):
    methodB("argvalue", kwargs)
```

How do I make sure that the **kwargs in methodA gets passed as **kwargs to methodB?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Put the asterisks before the kwargs variable. This makes Python pass the variable (which is assumed to be a dictionary) as keyword arguments.

```
methodB("argvalue", **kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't know how many times I've had to look up this thing - it's so simple and yet. Thanks for putting it up even though it's obvious :)

Answer (score 2):

As an aside: When using functions instead of methods, you could also use functools.partial:

```
import functools

def foo(arg, **kwargs):
    ...

bar = functools.partial(foo, "argvalue")
```

The last line will define a function "bar" that, when called, will call foo with the first argument set to "argvalue" and all other functions just passed on:

```
bar(5, myarg="value")
```

will call

```
foo("argvalue", 5, myarg="value")
```

Unfortunately that will not work with methods.

Comment: What does that actually do? What has it got to do with the question?

Answer (score 1):

Some experimentation and I figured this one out:

def methodA(arg, **kwargs):
    methodB("argvalue", **kwargs)

Seems obvious now...